# Emacs Haskell interactive mode in custom shell

Tags: haskell, emacs

I'd like to customize the behavior of `haskell-process-load-or-reload` (which is usually bound to `C-c C-l` and loads a file in a new GHCi session) such that GHCi starts in a custom shell.

Alternatively, what's a way to ensure the new GHCi process sees environment variables declared in `.bashrc`?

Thanks!